# Unity: 3D top-down rotate item around player

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, game-physics

I'm trying to get an object to always be "in front" of the player, from a top down perspective. Here's screenshots demonstrating what I'm trying to do.

[image]

So as you can see, when the blue capsule (player) picks up the green capsule (item), the item correctly hovers in front of the player (indicated by the z-axis blue arrow), but when the player turns in any other direction, the item doesn't follow, and instead stays in exactly the same position relative to the player.

[image]

My player controller script looks as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

  public float movementSpeed = 10;

  private Rigidbody body;
  private Vector2 movement;

  void Start() {
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
  }

  void Update() {
    movement.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    movement.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
  }

  void FixedUpdate() {
    body.velocity = new Vector3(movement.x * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, movement.y * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    // this is what updates the direction of the blue arrow in the direction of player movement
    if(movement.x != 0 || movement.y != 0) {
      body.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(body.velocity);
    }
  }
}
```

And here's my pickup script (where the item's position is supposed to be updated):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Pickup : MonoBehaviour {

  private GameObject item;
  public float carryDistance = 1;

  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Item")) {
      item = collision.gameObject;
    }
  }

  void Update() {
    if(item) {
      item.transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, carryDistance);
    }
  }
}
```

So to reiterate my question: How can I update the item's position such that it's always hovering next to the player on the side of the blue arrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using players transform.forward

```cs
item.transform.position = transform.position + (transform.forward * carryDistance) 
+ (Vector3.up * carryHeight);
```

Alternatively you can just add empty **child gameobject** to the player, position it in front of the player and use its transform position and rotation to position the picked up object.

```cs
public class Pickup : MonoBehaviour {

  public Transform pickupPositionTransform;
  private GameObject item;
  public float carryDistance = 1;

  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Item")) {
      item = collision.gameObject;
    }
  }

  void Update() {
    if(item) {
      item.transform.position = pickupPositionTransform.position;
      item.transform.rotation = pickupPositionTransform.rotation;
    }
  }
}
```